# upper bound of the expectation of the maximum of a bunch of random variables

Tags: probability, expected-value, order-statistics

I met one technical problem in my project, and I wish some reference here..

Suppose $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ are independent random variables. Are there some inequalities that give upper bound of $\mathbb{E}[\max_{1\leq i\leq n}X_i]$?

By now I only know one such inequality give by [Aven (1985)](https://doi.org/10.2307/3213876), that is, if $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is a sequence of random variables, then

$\mathbb{E}[\max_{1\leq i\leq n}X_i] \leq \max_{1\leq i\leq n}\mathbb{E}[X_i]+\sqrt{\frac{n-1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nVar(X_i)}$

Above inequality does not use the fact that $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ are independent. I was wondering if there are some other similar inequalities that I can consider.

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you know anything about their distribution?

Comment: @TnilkImaniq No. I actually want to show my conclusion is true for any distribution with few constraints, like $\mathbb{E}[X_i]$ and $Var(X_i)$ are uniformly bounded.

Comment: just google this http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gautamd/Files/maxGaussians.pdf

Comment: How tight do you want the bounds? For example $\displaystyle \mathbb{E}[\max_{1\leq i\leq n}X_i] \le \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[|X_i|]$

Comment: @AndrásSalamon I guess he is using $\max_{1\leq i\leq n}X_i \leq \max_{1\leq i\leq n}|X_i| \leq \sum_{i=1}^n |X_i|$.